# Integrating java applet into laravel 4 php project

Tags: java, php, laravel, laravel-4

I have searched on the internet and could not find a valuable information on how to integrate java applet(java program) into laravel 4 php project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't your Java applet loaded using HTML? You just have to put the loading tag int your view:

Let's say this is your views/home.php:

```
<Html>
    <Head>
        <Title>Java Example</Title>
    </Head>

    <Body>
        This is my page<br>
        Below you see an applet<br>
        <br>
        <Applet Code="MyApplet.class" width=200 Height=100></Applet>
    </Body>
</Html>
```

Now you just have to use it in Laravel:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
     return View::make('home');
});
```